# ASP.NET MVC 3 + Windows Authentication + Database Login check

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-3

I need some insight on the proper way to setup an ASP.NET MVC 3 web app where the users are logged in two ways:

1. They are part of the Domain (Windows Authentication)
2. The application's user table/store says they have access to the application

To handle the first requirement I am setting the authenication element to Windows in the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

The second one is the one that is a bit trickier.  My current thought was to utilize the HttpApplications AuthenticationRequested event.  So the code might look something like this:

```
void MvcApplication_AuthenticateRequest( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
  var formsAuthTicket = GetFormsAuthTicket();
  if ( formsAuthTicket == null || formsAuthTicket.Expired )
  {
    var userHasAccess = true; //TODO: Ask the someone if the user has access
    if ( userHasAccess )
    {
      FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket( 1,
        HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name,
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes( 1 ),
        true,
        HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name );

      string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt( authTicket );

      this.Response.Cookies.Remove( FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName );
      this.Response.Cookies.Add( new HttpCookie( FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket ) );
    }
    else 
      throw new HttpException( 401, "User is not authorized" );
  }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is better way to implement it in ASP.NET MVC by creating global authorization filter

Comment: Auhtorization filter would be too late in the game.  Authorization is typically used for checking the current user has access to a given controller/action.

Comment: I don't see any difference between access to all controllers and access to application if you don't have any resources in your application access to which is not controlled by ASP.NET MVC